What would it take to have voting by mail be a constitutional right in the USA?
This question is related to this one.
COVID brought voting by mail into the spotlight. What would it take to have the absolute right to vote by mail? Is it as easy as just amending the constitution, which is not easy at all or is there another way to mandate that all states offer voting by mail?

Frame challenge: all states already offer vote by mail for valid reasons (e.g. medical); broad in-person early voting is simpler and more secure for convenience. In my state, they simply open the polls for 2 weeks, including nights and weekends. There's never a line, you can go to any station in your county (I go to the one by work), they have accessible machines, if there's problems you can try later, you don't need a witness for absentee ballots or signature challenges, no concerns about getting ballots lost or delayed in the mail or driving it to the post office/drop box for security.

@user71659 I would consider it more convenient to send a letter by mail. Other people may feel differently. Strikes me as quite the elegant solution.

@NeilMeyer: The governments of California, Colorado, Hawaii, Nevada, Oregon, Utah, Vermont, and Washington agree with you.

The title and the body of the question don't match. The title asks only about a constitutional right, while the body asks if there might be other (presumably legislative) approaches.

By definition, making it a constitutional right would require amending the constitution.

@MJD Nah, Donald Trump acquired the constitutional rights to attempt a coup without any amendment required.

@user71659: It's great that your particular county operates enough polling stations to provide the good experience you describe, but the other ~1,000 counties in the US may not be up to the same standard.

The Elections Clause of the U.S. Constitution (Article I, Section 4) is understood to give the federal government broad power to regulate federal elections.  This is why, for example, the Uniformed and Overseas Citizens Absentee Voting Act is constitutional.  Similarly, people can to register to vote by affirming their citizenship under penalty of perjury but need not necessarily provide documentary evidence.  This was a provision of the National Voter Registration Act that was upheld in Arizona v. Inter Tribal Council of Arizona (2012).  Based on these precedents, it seems likely that a law requiring all states to provide absentee ballots for all voters in federal elections would pass constitutional muster.  (That said, stare decisis ain't what it used to be;  if such a law was challenged and went to the Supreme Court, the outcome might be different this time.)
However, this federal authority is not generally seen to extend to the regulation of state & local elections. So requiring states to provide absentee ballots for these elections would probably require a constitutional amendment.
As linked above, one state (Arizona) currently has a dual-ballot system, under which voters must provide documentary evidence of citizenship to vote in state elections, but can vote on a "federal-only" ballot if they merely affirm their citizenship under penalty of perjury.  If Congress enacted a National No-Excuse Absentee Ballot Act, one could easily imagine some states simply going along with it and changing their laws to allow absentee ballots in their own elections, while other states might stick to their guns and enacting an Arizona-like system where no-excuse absentee ballots would be federal-only.
Finally, as noted in the comments and in reirab's answer, a federal No-Excuse Absentee Ballot Act would not be a Constitutional right, since this act wouldn't be part of the Constitution.  In particular, this means that a subsequent hypothetical Congress could repeal this hypothetical act just as easily as a hypothetical Congress could enact it.

The only way to make it a Constitutional right is to amend the Constitution. Which is indeed hard to do, which is by design. Creating a new constitutional right (or constitutional power of the government or anything else constitutional) is not supposed to be easy and is supposed to require broad, nationwide agreement.
The Constitution does grant some powers to regulate federal elections to the federal government as Michael's answer discusses, however, this does not extend to creating constitutional rights of any sort as the question title asks about. The only legal way to do that is to amend the Constitution. Since such a regulation does not and cannot create a constitutional right, even if it were passed by Congress and signed by the President and survived any court challenges, a future Congress and President could just as easily repeal it.
The whole point of a constitutional right is that it requires amending the Constitution to remove it. Which also means that creating it requires amending the Constitution. Again, that this requires broad, nationwide support is very much a feature and not a bug.
Technically speaking, you can also stack the Supreme Court with justices who will rule something which is clearly not actually a constitutional right somehow is one anyway and that would de facto create such a right. However, as recent examples have shown, that can just as easily be undone by later justices ruling that said right does not actually exist in the Constitution.
Another option is to convince enough courts (likely including the Supreme Court) that something is a necessary consequence of something which is already in the Constitution and, therefore, should already be considered a constitutional right. A sufficiently convincing argument that a right to universal mail-in voting necessarily derives an existing provision of the Constitution would likely prove difficult to construct, though. And, of course, this still leaves open the possibility of future courts finding it less convincing and it being overturned.

The most common way to make something a Constitutional right, arguably, is to get 5 (of 9) people to agree with you. E.g. Griswold, Gideon, Miranda, Obergefell, Heller, &c.

@nitsua60 Yes, the last paragraph addresses that (though, honestly, Heller doesn't really belong on that list, considering it's stated as a right in the 2nd Amendment.) But, as described in the answer, overturning such a decision merely requires getting a future 5 of the 9 to agree that it wasn't correct. While it is possible for the SCOTUS to just outright ignore a right spelled out explicitly in an amendment, it's generally much more difficult to get justices who are willing to do that, since it's overtly subverting the Constitution they're sworn to uphold. Not impossible, but more difficult

I guess I was trying to draw a distinction: you don't need to stack the Court beforehand, just convince 5. (I'm not aware of arguments that FDR, Eisenhower, and Johnson colluded to create the Miranda majority, for instance.)

@nitsua60 Ah, fair enough. Edited to address that possibility.
